# AngularJS send updated data to php page via $http.post

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have just added the functionality to edit a table cell in my angularJS app. What I would like to do now is have the changes reflected in the database by sending the updated data to my PHP script, I'm a little stuck on how to actually resend the updated table.

My Angular Table in question:

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in resultValue=(data | filter:{'type':typeFilter} | filter:dateFilter | filter:proFilter | filter:cusFilter | filter:taskFilter | filter:nameFilter)">

    <td class="jid" ng-hide="viewField">{{c.journal_id}}</td>
    <td ng-show="modifyField"><input type="text" class="in1" ng-model="c.journal_id" /></td>

    <td class="wda" ng-hide="viewField">{{c.work_date}}</td>
    <td ng-show="modifyField"><input type="text" class="in1" ng-model="c.work_date" /></td> 

</tr>
     <button ng-hide="viewField" ng-click="modify(c)">Modify</button>
     <button ng-show="modifyField" ng-click="update(c)">Update</button>
```

The controller thanks to a SO answer for the edit part:

```
    journal.controller('dbCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

          $scope.loadData = function () {
        $http.get("http://localhost/slick/journalFetch.php").success(function(data){
                $scope.data = data;
            }).error(function() {
                $scope.data = "error in fetching data";
            });
}

  $scope.modify = function(c){

            $scope.modifyField = true;
            $scope.viewField = true;
        };


  $scope.update = function(c){
            $scope.modifyField = false;
            $scope.viewField = false;

          //AM I ABLE TO RESEND THE UPDATED (c) DATA HERE TO THE DATABASE ?

             $http({
                method: "post",
                url: "update.php",
                data: {
                    //if so how to retrieve updated c data here?
                }
             }); 
            };
  $scope.loadData();
}]);
```

Comment: Actually you are struck to pass the values using $http to php file am i got right?

Comment: @Jagadeesh Only after the values of the table `(c)` are edited using the `.modfy` and `.update function` I would then like to send the -updated- data to the php file

Comment: You would send another Ajax call to your server to update and receive a response. Check out using using angularjs $resource though. You can create a resource for say User and it already has basic options for getting a list of users, getting one user, editing a user, etc. Then in your controller you would only do a User.$save()

Comment: As my understanding after you update the values, and you need the those changes in your php file. Right? If so you can do like this in your update function i.e:  `$http.post(url, {userName: $scope.userName, password: $scope.password}).success(function (response) { }` So you get the values in your php file using this json data

Comment: @Hayden Thanks I will look into $resource and possibly switch my angular APP in the near future, but I still would like to know if the above is possible for learning, and quick implementation for the time being!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to update the entire table with a single `Update` button click. Your current code is trying to access `c` outside the `tr` element which makes `c` out of scope for the `button`.

Try passing `data` variable to the `update` function.

Comment: That part of my app works fine, I think you are missing the problem here.